# SQL Query - Left Join or Union?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do I write a SQL query to find out what the group ID is and then display list of Options from that Group ID.

I can do it by two queries, for example:

```
//Get the group ID 
SELECT option_group_id FROM options WHERE id =14122

//Now get a list of OptionID from that group ID
SELECT id, name FROM options WHERE option_group_id = 999
```

How do I put this into 1 query?

Comment: I have tried LEFT JOIN: `SELECT o1.id, O1.option_group_id FROM options O1
  Left Join options as O2 ON O2.option_group_id = O1.option_group_id
WHERE o1.id = 14122` but don't work.

Comment: Well, you could post that in the original question, report what it did, and ask why it did not work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither. You use an inner join against the same table:

```
select o2.id, o2.name
from options o1
inner join options o2 on o2.option_group_id = o1.option_group_id
where o1.id = 14122
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a subquery to retrieve the group's id:

```
select  id
,       name
from    options
where   option_group_id = 
        (
        select  option_group_id
        from    options
        where   id = 14122
        )
```

Answer (score 3):

Basically:

- if you want more columns => join
- if you want more rows => union

In this case:

```
SELECT toGetData.id
     , toGetData.name
  FROM options toGetId
  join options toGetData on toGetData.option_group_id = toGetId.option_group_id
 wHERE toGetId.id = 14122
```

Comment: +1 I think this best addresses what the OP is confused about.